# How to make a good gradient with lots of colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient, color-theory

Any tips on making some killer gradients like this?

I am in love with this gradient:

[image]

(Image by **Ivan Bobrov** via Dribble:
https://dribbble.com/shots/1763092-K-mark )

How can I achieve something like the example?

Comment: well that certainly isnt "a gradient" its about 20!

Comment: I thought it was only one gradient with a lot of colors, but the direction is not linear. My guess it's he used multiple gradients + layer masks

Comment: Illustrator... Gradient Mesh.

Comment: Is it possible to do it also in PS? Feel free to answer the question, so I can accept the answer

Comment: If I would to do this in photoshop, I'd most likely use soft round brushes. If I was making a logo I wouldn't use photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **Gradient Mesh** in Adobe Illustrator....

[image]

[image]

But it will take some care and patience.

For *Photoshop*.. really it's all just brushes and blending via transparencies.

I'm sure there are 3D modeling applications that may be easier to use the Illustrator's meshes and more controllable than painting in Photoshop.

Answer (score 3):

You can use many shapes one atop another with simple gradient (not Gradient Mesh).

[image]